# How to use range with greater than and less than

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how I can use the greater than (>) or less than (<) with ranges. For example, if I have a variable x and I want to compare it to y - I want to say if x is less (or greater) than y by a given number. For instance, if x is 50 or further away from y. How can I represent this in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to say if x is less than y by 10

You write it very close to how you say it:

```
if (x < y - 10)
```

Or if you mean *exactly* 10 less:

```
if (x == y - 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I represent it if I want to say: if x is 50 or further away from y? Or between two numbers like 30 and 50.

Comment: @Abdi: Define "further away"

Comment: @Abdi: As in, do you mean less than or greater than? Or either? If either, you can use `if (Math.abs(x - y) > 50)`, or `var diff = Math.abs(x - y); if (diff > 30 && diff < 50)` if you want to check for the values 31-49, inclusive.

Comment: I'm building a "Hot or Cold" game. In this game, the computer randomly selects a number, and the player then tries to guess the number. The player gets feedback for each guess – “hot” if their guess was close, and “cold” if their guess was far. I want to use values to tell the user they are very close to guessing the number. For example, if a user is 50 or further away from the secret number, I want to tell them they are “Ice cold”, if they are between 30 and 50 they are “cold”, if they are between 20 and 30 they are warm, between 10 and 20 hot, and between 1 and 10 “very hot”. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdi: Then my note above (which I may well have been typing as you were typing :-) ) should get you there.

Answer (score 2):

According to the updated question `I want to say if x is less (or greater) than y by a given number` you should write it as follows

```
var givenNumber = 10;

if(Math.abs(x-y) === givenNumber) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The original question was asking about if x is less than y **by 10**, so `x` is further away from `y` by `10` steps (he did not mention 10 steps or more)

Comment: That's not your fault but this answer is now outdated. I suggest you to update it to fit the updated question.

Comment: I updated the answer to match the the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking if `x + 10 < y`.